# How to make my codes right. using td's ad tr tags

Tags: html

I created some codes here. When I tried it on my webpage the rows (the options (e.g. MENDEL, DARWIN, FUNNY FACTS)) my problem is that it is not equal. please help me.
codes below. the widths are not equal.

```
<html>
<head><title>DARMENTEUR</title></head>
<body background="bg.jpg">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br>
<h1 align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:54pt"><marquee direction="left" behaviour="scroll">DARMENTEUR</marquee></h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="information.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station
;font-size:14pt;color:white;">DARWIN</p></a></td>

<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="gallery2.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:white;">MENDEL<*/p></a></td>

<td style="width:10%;">
<a href="quotes12.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:white;">PASTEUR</p></a></td>

<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="hi.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:white;">MINI QUIZ</p></a></td>

<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="hi.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:white;">FUNNY FACTS</p></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="width:400px;">
<iframe src="info.html" width="1320px" height="1000" name="t1" id="t1">
<p> iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you heard of [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with the width and height you are specifying for the iframe tag, it will result in all the columns becoming unequal (as far as i am understanding your question you want all the columns to be of fix width), check the below code I have made the necessary changes this will make all the columns of equal width:

```
<html>
<head><title>DARMENTEUR</title></head>
<body background="bg.jpg">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br>
<h1 align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;color:#000;font-size:54pt"><marquee direction="left" behaviour="scroll">DARMENTEUR</marquee></h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="information.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station
;font-size:14pt;color:black;">DARWIN</p></a></td>

<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="gallery2.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:black;">MENDEL</p></a></td>

<td style="width:10%;">
<a href="quotes12.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:black;">PASTEUR</p></a></td>

<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="hi.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:black;">MINI QUIZ</p></a></td>

<td style="width:20%;">
<a href="hi.html" target="t1"><p align="center" style="font-family:imagination station;font-size:15pt;color:black;">FUNNY FACTS</p></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" style="width:400px; " align="center">
<iframe src="info.html" name="t1" id="t1">
<p> iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```